# WPF Activate two windows

Tags: wpf

I've got two windows which Need to be shown together. Problem is, when they are in the back and the user opens one of these via alt-tab, the other window is still in the back

By now, I managed to do this with

```
private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OtherWindow.Activate();
    this.Activate();
}
```

in both windows, but it creates Kind of a flickering and I was wondering if there is a "cleaner" way to achieve this

Long Story short: when one window is activated, the other one should be too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Window Owner property, if your 2 window have same Owner or one window is owner to second one, then activating one of them should be activate another also.

Window W = new Window() { Owner=this }

Comment: Wow first of all: Exactly what I wanted :D ; Second: I had the additional Problem when you use alt+tab that both Windows are displayed as suggestions, now only the owner-window is displayed. GREAT! (PS please inlcude `Window W = new Window() { Owner=this }` to your answer)

Comment: sorry you want to just include that code in my answer?

Comment: Yes perfect, if someone else got the same problem he/she is going to find the answer faster, thanks <3